# react native: what is the way to get only the `zoneData[index].Zone_ID` in the onPress button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

what is the way to get only the `zoneData[index].Zone_ID` in the onPress button ?
the below example take some data from table .
in this situation now while i press button so it return everything but i need only the `zoneData[index].Zone_ID` .
I have tried all kinds of ways but without success and would love to know how the right way.

```
import React from 'react';
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
import {View, Button, ScrollView} from 'react-native';

const db = SQLite.openDatabase ({
  name: 'Dogmim_DB',
  createFromLocation: '~ / Dogmim_DB.db',
});

export default class SQLiteScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super ();
    SQLite.DEBUG = true;
  }

  SelectQuery () {
    const promise = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
      db.transaction ((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql (
          'SELECT Successor_Zones, Water_Source_Groups FROM tblUserConnectResponseData',
          [],
          (_, result) => {
            for (let i = 0; i <result.rows.length; i ++) {
              //// Successor_Zones
              const Successor_Zones = result.rows.item (i) ['Successor_Zones'];
              const zoneData = JSON.parse (Successor_Zones);
              if (zoneData.length> 0) {
                for (let index = 0; index <zoneData.length; index ++) {
                  console.log ('Zone_ID:' + zoneData [index] .Zone_ID);
                  console.log ('Zone_Name:' + zoneData [index] .Zone_Name);
                }
              }
              //// Water_Source_Groups
              const Water_Source_Groups = result.rows.item (i) [
                'Water_Source_Groups'
              ];

              const waterData = JSON.parse (Water_Source_Groups);
              if (waterData.length> 0) {
                for (let index = 0; index <waterData.length; index ++) {
                  console.log ('Group_Name:' + waterData [index] .Group_Name);
                  console.log ('Zone_ID:' + waterData [index] .Zone_ID);
                }
              }
            }
            resolve ({
              isAny: true,
            });
          },
          (_, err) => {
            reject (err);
          }
        );
      });
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button onPress = {this.SelectQuery} title = "Press Me" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you insert a `console.log(zoneData)` right after the `if (zoneData.length> 0) {` and post the result? We need to know what the data looks like first.

Comment: [{"Zone_ID": 66, "Zone_Name": "Herzel"}]